# Making a set of sets returns unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, set, append

```
S=set()
for i in range(1,100):
    for j in range(1,100):
        for k in range(1,100):
            if i**2+j**2==k**2:
                S.add(([i,j,k]))
print S
```

and the error is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-606e3083d711> in <module>()
      4         for k in range(1,100):
      5             if i**2+j**2==k**2:
----> 6                 S.add(([i,j,k]))
      7 print S

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I just want to get all the distinct Pythagorean triples [for me (3,4,5)=(4,3,5)]. That's why I'm doing it with sets, but for some reason I can't append a set to my original set S...

Comment: Have you googled the error? You can't hash lists as they are mutable.

Comment: You can only add immutable types to a set like `tuple` or `frozenset`.

Comment: Let `j` loop from `i` to `100` and `k` from `j` to `100` and you can avoid removing repeated items.

Comment: Just adding the tuples to a built-in set won’t do that for you anyway, because in Python, `(3, 4, 5) != (4, 3, 5)`. Do what Page David said. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type error Unhashable type:set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577724/type-error-unhashable-typeset)

Comment: See the official Python docs under Built-in Types: [Set Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element of set need to be hashable, which means immutable, use tuple instead of list.
Or you can use a frozenset.

For "`get all the distinct Pythagorean triples [for me (3,4,5)=(4,3,5)].`", you can restrict the `i` as smaller one, `j` as larger one, sample code here:

```
S = set()
for i in range(1, 100):
    # include i to support i=j case
    for j in range(i, 100):
        for k in range(1, 100):
            if i ** 2 + j ** 2 == k ** 2:
                S.add((i, j, k))
```

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a set of lists, just sort the list and convert to tuples (to avoid dupes):

```
S=set()
for i in range(1,100):
    for j in range(1,100):
        for k in range(1,100):
            if i**2+j**2==k**2:
                # Notice I've changed squared brackets to round brackets for tuples, and sorted the list, so that duplicates are eliminated.
                S.add(tuple(sorted([i,j,k])))
print(S)
```

`

I am assuming run time efficiency is not important for now.