# Merging a list of dictionaries based on common key values but with nested dict of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to wrap my head around (what I feel) is a way too complicated dict/list to represent the relationship between items.

```
mappings = [{'switches': ['switch1', 'switch2'], 'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute001', 'servers': ['server1', 'server2']}]},
            {'switches': ['switch1', 'switch2'], 'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute002', 'servers': ['server3', 'server4']}]},
            {'switches': ['switch3', 'switch4'], 'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute003', 'servers': ['server5', 'server6']}]},
            {'switches': ['switch3', 'switch4'], 'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute004', 'servers': ['server7', 'server8', 'server9']}]},
            {'switches': ['switch5', 'switch6'], 'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute005', 'servers': ['server10', 'server11', 'server12']}]},
            {'switches': ['switch5', 'switch6'], 'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute006', 'servers': ['server13', 'server14', 'server15', 'server16']}]}]
```

As you can see, it's a list of dict, where the value is sometimes another list of dict.

The issue I'm having is that the starting data are holding "duplicates". For example, if you look at the key value of "switches", you can see that the list holding "switch1" + "switch2" are present twice. It's valid as the relationship data is unique.

I would like to find a way to transform that dict into something like the following :

```
end_mapping = [{'switches': ['switch1', 'switch2'], 'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute001', 'servers': ['server1', 'server2']},
                                                                      {'compute_name': 'compute002', 'servers': ['server3', 'server4']}]},
               {'switches': ['switch3', 'switch4'], 'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute003', 'servers': ['server5', 'server6']},
                                                                      {'compute_name': 'compute004', 'servers': ['server7', 'server8', 'server9']}]},
               {'switches': ['switch5', 'switch6'], 'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute005', 'servers': ['server10', 'server11', 'server12']},
                                                                      {'compute_name': 'compute006', 'servers': ['server13', 'server14', 'server15', 'server16']}]}
              ]
```

In this data set, the switches key values are unique and I've "merged" the relationships dictionaries.

I've been banging my head around this but haven't found a way so far.

I have a starting point with :

```
new_list_of_dict = []
for mapping_dict_a in mappings:
    for mapping_dict_b in mappings:
        if set(mapping_dict_b['switches']) == set(mapping_dict_a['switches']):
            same = True
            mapping_dict_a['relationships'].append(mapping_dict_b['relationships'])
            new_list_of_dict.append(mapping_dict_a)
            break
        else:
            same = False
            print('NOT SAME!')
```

But it's not working so far (I'm sure it's wrong ;) - and I end up with either an infinite loop or way too much data in the final_dict.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Any idea where the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so I came up with something that should work, though it is a hack. Let me know how it goes.

```
# given the mappings var you provided in your example:
switches = [item.get('switches') for item in mappings]
unique_switches = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in switches)]

unique_mapping = []
for switch in unique_switches:
    relationship_list = []
    for item in mappings:
        if item.get('switches') == switch:
            relationship_list.append(item['relationships'])
    unique_mapping.append({'switches': switch, 'relationships': relationship_list})
```

`unique_mapping` should result in:

```
[{'switches': ['switch5', 'switch6'],
  'relationships': [[{'compute_name': 'compute005',
     'servers': ['server10', 'server11', 'server12']}],
   [{'compute_name': 'compute006',
     'servers': ['server13', 'server14', 'server15', 'server16']}]]},
 {'switches': ['switch1', 'switch2'],
  'relationships': [[{'compute_name': 'compute001',
     'servers': ['server1', 'server2']}],
   [{'compute_name': 'compute002', 'servers': ['server3', 'server4']}]]},
 {'switches': ['switch3', 'switch4'],
  'relationships': [[{'compute_name': 'compute003',
     'servers': ['server5', 'server6']}],
   [{'compute_name': 'compute004',
     'servers': ['server7', 'server8', 'server9']}]]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) & why `frozenset` not `set` refer this post [`unhashable type: 'set'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577724/type-error-unhashable-typeset)

```
results = {}

for v in mappings:
    key = frozenset(v['switches'])

    if results.get(key):
        results[key]['relationships'].append(v['relationships'])
    else:
        results[key] = v

print(list(results.values()))
```

```
[{'relationships': [{'compute_name': 'compute001',
                     'servers': ['server1', 'server2']},
                    [{'compute_name': 'compute002',
                      'servers': ['server3', 'server4']}]],
  'switches': ['switch1', 'switch2']},
...
}]
```

Comment: Cool solution, but if you run this code snippet in a Jupyter notebook environment, for example, the relationships key will grow with the terminal item in the initial relationships list.

Comment: @IraH. It could due to object's having same ref, you can fix that by using deepcopy ```import copy; copy.deepcopy(v['relationships'])``` then append.