# passing python variables to dash html components

Tags: python, variables, plotly-dash

i am trying to access value of a python variable in dash html components and it gives me an error.
This is what i have already tried.

```
    num = 78
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            html.H5("TEMP", className="card-title"),
            html.P("This card is number ",{{num}}),
    dbc.Button("Go somewhere", color="primary"),
        ], style = {"color":"black" }
    )
```

the idea is to show a number that is stored in num as part of contents of a P element.
i get the following error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

does anybody know what i can do to solve this.

Comment: please post the error

Comment: @UmairMubeen i edited the question to include error

Comment: Hi Arnold. yes, post the error please. Also check latest Dash conventions at https://dash.plotly.com/dash-daq/numericinput. You may want to try using html.P(children=["...text", num]) instead.

Comment: @TeilaRei i don't to accept the value from the front end, i want to use it from the variable already been declared within the code

Comment: @Arnold please check this post hope this will solve your error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577724/type-error-unhashable-typeset

Comment: That is fine. You still can use the same conventions. Try the code I suggested, and try searching on dash community. Also, to troubleshoot, try just this: html.P(num) if that shows, it means you need to separate the value from the text. Another option, html.P("text".format(str(num)))

Comment: @TeilaRei thank you. html.P(num) worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the answer from the comment above, since it has worked.
Set numerical variable should be accessed directly, as a child of a paragraph, depending on how you want it to show.
Instead of

```
html.P("This card is number ",{{num}}
```

Use the solution that worked in this case

```
html.P(num)
```

or explore other options, e.g.

```
html.P("text".format(str(num)))
html.P(children=["...text", num])
```

Here is [html.P documentation page](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/p)